# How to check .Net version which is installed on my machine using wmic command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I just want to check .Net version which is installed on my machine using wmic command in batch file.

Below command i used , but its not working.

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended%%'" get version
```

Can anyone please help me out from this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You could just the latest installation directory in the mincrosoft FrameWork. Easier and 10x faster.

Comment: In what way is it not working? That command appears to work perfectly fine on my Win7 machine.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to show us some sample output, we could progress this. I get no output whatever from this command.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have that version, you should get a message saying "No Instance(s) Available"

I would recommend

```
 wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%Microsoft .NET%%'" get version
```

This way you can see all versions that are installed including 4.0